# EF Code First Migrations - two assemblies - looking at wrong config file

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, model-view-controller, .net-assembly, entity-framework-migrations

I have an MVC5 project with EF6 and I am using two assemblies, one for the main website "Goods" with controllers membership stuff and the other, separate assembly "Goods.Models" with business domain and business logic, which is also using EF6 and connecting to the same MySQL database.

When I try to create a migration in the second assembly I get error:

```
    System.TypeInitializationException: 
The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration`1' threw an exception. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: 
The DbConfiguration type 'Goods.Setup.MySqlConfiguration, Goods' specified in the application config file could not be loaded. 
Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is available to the running application. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260883 for more information. --->
```

OK so **it can't find "Goods.Setup.MySqlConfiguration, Goods"**

I have the config files in both assemblies, one from the main front end assembly "Goods":

```
<entityFramework codeConfigurationType="Goods.Setup.MySqlConfiguration, Goods">...
```

And the other in the "Goods.Models" assembly:

```
<entityFramework codeConfigurationType="Goods.Models.MySQLSetup.MySqlConfiguration, Goods.Models">...
```

I made sure I am selecting the Goods.Models assembly in the PM console, **but the error indicates that the migration framework is looking at the config file of the "Goods" assembly.**

How can I fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by adding -StartUpProjectName parameter like so:

add-migration -StartUpProjectName Goods.Models

It appears it's not enough to set the default project in PM console